# How to fit text box size to text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs5, resize, artboard

I want to fit the artboard to selected art (two text boxes) - the text boxes are larger than the text inside them - how do I fit (shrink) them to wrap tightly around my text?

Illustrator version - CS5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Illustrator doesn't (as of 5.1) have a handy "fit frame to content" feature like InDesign. Just select the text frame and drag the handles inward until the frame is snug to the text.

Answer (score 16):

This is now a built-in feature as of 2014 in Adobe Illustrator CC. You'll find it under Type > Area Type Options > Auto Size.

Comment: In CC19 I don't see this option.  Has it moved?  @Matt M.

Answer (score 9):

There's a script for that. (this is probably the script Joonas' comment alludes to - works just fine in CS6).

(to then fit the art board after fitting the text box, use the art board tool and click on the text box)

Courtesy of [Kelso Cartography](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/scripts/nvkelso/) who have loads of great scripts (their scripts to switch point and area text are also highly recommended), you can [download the Fit Text To Content script here](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/scripts/nvkelso/FitToTextContent_v2.jsx). It does exactly what it says on the tin - scales (up or down) a text area's text frame to fit the height of the lines of text.

Here's a 'before' and 'after' of this script, plus its cousin also from Kelso Cartography, [Fit Text To Content Width](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/scripts/nvkelso/FitToTextContentWidth.jsx), resizing a text frame to remove unused space (pic courtesy of [vectips](http://vectips.com/tips-and-tricks/fit-text-frame-to-content-script/)):

[image]

Here are teh codez in case that link goes down. All credit to original author. Just save it as a .js file in your `illustrator/presets/[some language code]/scripts` folder then reboot Illustrator:

```
// FitToTextContent_Depth
// Nathaniel Vaughn KELSO
// Last modified: 2008.March.29
// Created: 2007.July.8 
// at Hyattsville, MD
// Version 2
// (c) nvkelso2008@gmail.com (but remove the 2008 bit)
// DESC: Fits the text frame (rectangular path shapes only!) to fit the text content. 
// DESC: Will either shrink or expand the depth of the text box as appropriate. 
// TODO: Extend to work with text on a line (PATHTEXT)
// TODO: watch for 4 point paths that are not rectangular
// TODO: watch for 4 point paths that are rotated

var includeExtraLines = 0.5;

if(documents.length > 0) {
    doc = activeDocument;
    mySelection = activeDocument.selection;

    // If there are enough to process
    if (mySelection instanceof Array)
    {
        // For each of the selected items
        for(i=0; i<mySelection.length; i++) {
            // That are textFrames
            if (mySelection[i].typename == "TextFrame" && mySelection[i].kind == TextType.AREATEXT ) {
                obj = mySelection[i];

                // We only want to do this on rectangular text areas
                // TODO: Take care of rotation issues from MakePointType script
                if( obj.textPath.pathPoints.length == 4 ) {
                    objTop = obj.top;
                    objLeft = obj.left;

                    // Make the new point type object and locate it
                    // Make sure the new object is in the same Z stacking order as the original
                    copy1 = obj.duplicate(obj, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
                    //copy1.move(obj, ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);

                    // now make the text box much bigger, but not absurdly big
                    // TODO: This could be better approximated by itterating thru all the WORDS in the textFrame and 
                    // comparing it to all the WORDS in each of the visible text LINES. Then apply the difference / total words to the scaling
                    if( copy1.height * 10 < 2000 ) {
                        copy1.textPath.height = copy1.height * 10;
                    } else {
                        copy1.textPath.height = 2000;
                    }

                    howManyLines = copy1.lines.length;

                    outlineObject = copy1.duplicate();
                    outlineObject = outlineObject.createOutline();

                    targetHeight = outlineObject.height + includeExtraLines * (outlineObject.height / howManyLines );

                    // Now assign y-axis depth of the point text to the area text box
                    rect = obj.parent.pathItems.rectangle(copy1.textPath.top, copy1.textPath.left, obj.width, targetHeight);
                    copy2 = obj.parent.textFrames.areaText(rect);
                    copy2.selected = true;
                    rect.selected = true;

                    // Always delete these intermediate objects
                    outlineObject.remove();
                    copy1.remove();

                    // Now take care of the end and original objects
                    obj.textRange.duplicate(copy2); 
                    obj.remove();   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I install this on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to convert area type to point type. Maybe [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/V7BL32Ka-Jg) can help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112602)