# Text wrapping fill-last-line-first

Tags: typography, text, css, style-identification, html

I have a peculiar design for a web page that I have to implement from an already made design, and some of the text wrappings are filled bottom-up (in my case it's for bottom-left aligned thin text inside colored square tiles, looks better than it sounds). That is, in a block of text that wraps across multiple lines, the bottom line is filled first (horizontally), so that any remaining horizontal space after wrapping is left for the first line.

Is this a known kind of text wrapping and how could I implement it in a web page without manually adding line-breaks in the source text? Or could you at least name that "feature" so that I could google it?

Edit: For example, in the text "Here be the link" if there is not enough room on one line then the line should be rendered as "Here \n be the link" instead of the standard "Here be the \n link", where "\n" is a line break.

Comment: Could you add an image? I can't imagine it looking good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect you're talking about is called **Vertical Alignment**, in this case bottom vertical alignment. In design applications like InDesign (but not Illustrator [without hacking](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/10712/3327), *moan whinge moan...*) there's a simple button for it.

In HTML / CSS, [vertical alignment isn't so simple](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/). Vertical alignment for a table cell is easy, `vertical-align: bottom;` starts text at the bottom how you describe, but outside of table cells, vertical alignment refers to how images and other inline elements with height are aligned to each block of text.

You ***can*** however force a HTML div (or any block element) to have vertical alignment, by telling it to pretend it's a table cell with the CSS rule `display: table-cell;` (I've seen people say it has to be something pretending to be a table, or that this is somehow 'bad practice' - they've got it mixed up with regular HTML tables, it's fine like this). Then, you can add the CSS rule `vertical-align: bottom;` and it'll work.

Unfortunately, you need a workaround to make this work in old versions of internet explorer which ignore `display: table-cell;`, and it can be tricky to make this work where CSS `float`s are involved, which is commonly used for boxes in a line or columns (`table-cell`s don't float) - a grid of tiles as described in the question will almost certainly use `float`.

Here's a stripped down [**live editable example on the site JSbin**](http://jsbin.com/eloget/4/) demonstrating how to make it work everywhere, including old versions of IE, including in floated tiles. Hit the 'Edit in JSbin' button to see the code and to play around with it: there are lots of code comments explaining what's essential and what's optional.

The basic principle: use wrappers and a fallback trick for internet explorer with a `position: absolute;` wrapper and `position: relative;` content.

*(the random grey box is IE7 screwing up the JSbin edit button...)*

[image]

---

The simplest example for bottom alignment that works in old IE is this HTML:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><div class="old-ie"><![endif]-->

<div class="bottom wrapper">
<div class="content">
 This text is bottom aligned
</div>
</div>

<div class="middle wrapper">
<div class="content">
 This text is bottom aligned
</div>
</div>

<!--[if lte IE 7]></div><![endif]-->
```

...and this CSS:

```
/* for normal browsers... 
*******************/

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
}
.bottom .content {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.middle .content {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* make it more-or-less work in IE6, IE7 
*******************/

.old-ie {
    position: relative;
}
.old-ie .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.old-ie .content {
    position: relative;
}
.old-ie .bottom .wrapper, .old-ie .bottom .content {
    bottom: 0;
}
.old-ie .middle .wrapper {
    top: 50%;
}
.old-ie .middle .content {
    top: -50%;
}
```

---

Finally, here's [a link to a StackOverflow (coding Q&A site) answer I wrote a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224296/568458), explaining in a bit more detail if needed how to get `vertical-align` working cross-browser with floats (probably the trickiest case) and what the limitations are.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to write this up but I'm afraid you misunderstood me (or more likely I've explained it badly in the question). It's not a matter of a bottom vertical alignment, it's a matter of the "shape" of the wrapped text. For example, in the text "Here be the link" if there is not enough room on one line then the line should be rendered as "Here \n be the link" instead of standard "Here be the \n link".

Comment: Right, wasn't clear. That's a lot more difficult, if it has a name, I've never heard of it - people are likely to assume the unexpected break means something in the text, like a pause. For the web, you'll first need to vertical align to the bottom, then you'll need some Javascript that analyses the text and calculates  where to place a line break. That's a tricky programming problem and you should probably ask the programmers on stack overflow. I'd guess the best way would involve building a `visibility: hidden;` one word at a time from back to front, testing the width against the space.

Comment: P.s. if the purpose of this is to avoid a title, can't you just make the title `float: left;` or right in the tile? This would make the main tile text flow around the title and could be a more conventional way to make things work. Conventional is usually good in typography because if a reader is distracted puzzling out an unusual layout, they're paying less attention to the content.

Comment: I agree completely, but it's not really my choice, customers in-house designer made the design and I'm supposed to implement it... :(

Comment: Maybe I could use server-side to build tiles with bitmap backgrounds and recreate the tiles when the tile text changes in the CMS. It should be easier to do server-side since I could use real gfx libraries instead of JS. And with image caching it should be fast but it would still be image-heavy. Or I could try to convince the customer to give up this novelty text wrapping :)

Comment: You have my sympathy! If that type of alignment did exist, it would be called "top ragged" I imagine (the ragged side in typographic alignment is the uneven side).

Comment: The only thing I can think of that comes close is vertically justified text - which is like what you say but without the ragged top. Probably really hard to do for web, this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188969/is-there-any-way-to-vertically-justify-text-in-html  really it's a programming problem

Comment: The worst is that the design doesn't look half bad. The text is bottom-aligned in the tile and usually has about 3 lines of text, and when that last line is filled to the end it looks kinda better than with normal wrapping, which leaves a gap in the bottom-right part of the tile

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is the right site to ask this question but here is an example of what you need (for IE, works in 8 and above):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tile {width:200px; height:100px; background-color:#FFFF00; vertical-align:bottom; display:table-cell;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tile">123</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `vertical-align:bottom;` and `display:table-cell;` in the style and feel free to play with fonts, margins etc.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a top search result for this topic and the last answers were from 2013, I thought I would add a couple alternatives to using `display:table-cell;` in order to do vertical alignment (e.g. where the text fills up a box from bottom to top).

## 100% height pseudoelement to vertical-align against

You have an outer container (box) that the text will be positioned against.
You have an inline text element in the container that will contain the text and wrap if necessary.

A 100% height, 0 width pseudoelement is added to that outer container for the text element to vertical-align:bottom against.

Demo: https://codepen.io/matp/pen/jOedbpY

## use flexbox which makes vertical alignment easier

Flexbox is widely supported by non-dead browsers and is a good option for layouts that used to require more hacks.

Demo: https://codepen.io/matp/pen/VwEgjGY