# How can I align text in a text area vertically, in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

how can I align some text in any text area vertically? so I can align a label vertically and Horizontally in any text area, as if i align the text in a table cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after six years Adobe implemented this feature especially in Version 25 October 2020

[image]

now we can access this feature in the properties toolbar or in the Text area option dialogue box.

[image]

[image]

for more information please visit
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html#vertical-align

Answer (score 5):

You could use the

### Character Style

- Horizontal Scale
- Vertical Scale
  And maybe taking it a step further turn on the Asian font settings to access the Tate-chu-yoko and Warichu settings for the Vertical Up/Down alignment.

And also set up

### Paragraph Styles

- Advanced Character Formats
- Indents and Spacing

I use Indents to create the padding found in a HTML  box-model

There is also the same controls for Asian Characters mentioned above including Japanese Composition Settings.

It's all about learning the hacks until they move more into the Web Design aspect that was introduced in the CC version.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no option to vertically align text within a text box in Illustrator.

You might can try [this script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/10712/32888) which was posted as an answer on a similar question.

Comment: thank you .. it have just try it and the script didn't do what I am asking for. it just resize the area text boundaries to fit to the content. but it didn't align the text inside.

Comment: This is why I hate Adobe. They add new random things, but can't simplify the basics.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a negative baseline (Character panel > Show Options) to simulate vertical alignment. This is the only way that has worked well for me to visually center text in a text box with a colored background. Without using a negative baseline, the Type > Area Type Options > Offset > Inset spacing doesn't let you vertically center text in a text box.

Answer (score 3):

**If you have Illustrator CC 2020 (version 24.3)** which was released sometime in late August of 2020. One of the new features is the "Vertical text alignment" ability, described here https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/whats-new/2020-3.html#vertical-align and also https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html#vertical-align

It's under "Area Type Options..." in the "Type" menu - Perhaps this feature wasn't implemented when you posted the question?

[image]

---

*There is **no** ability to vertically align area text in its bounding area in legacy versions of Illustrator.* You **must** have v24.3 or newer.

Comment: Is that illustrator?

Comment: @joojaa, newest version just got vertical text alignment it seems.

Comment: @Wolff finally, the post would benefit from saying that it has been added so its not so confuing with conflicting info

Comment: @joojaa Perhaps you didn't read the opening sentence.

Comment: @JeremyMurray-Wakefield yes but it would be better to say that it as added and when. Its slmost certainly true that it didnt exsist when the question was originally asked.

Comment: -- Added version information. (this was *not* a feature until this year, in fact last month of this year. So, no, the user didn't have this ability in 2014 when the question was posed.)

Comment: Thank you @JeremyMurray-Wakefield I have been owned the new version for a long time and it was missing a feature in "whats's new" and I didn't notice it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may try "Type on a path Tool". It has an option of justifing the text vertically to path center, but first create path and put the text and then go to the Type menu to change its settings. You can justify it horizonatally from paragraph panel. Optioanlly you may set the opacity of the path to zero to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical text align is not available in illustrator. It is native to InDesign and I suspect it's left out deliberately because illustrator is not typography focused. It is a feature I would use on a daily basis when creating diagrams if it were available. I think it's a feature that should be added.

My fix is usually putting text in boxes and shrinking the texboxes down to fit snugly with the text (the last line disappears if you have gone too far) . Then using the normal vertical align tools to vertically align the text to something. It's cumbersome but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was a little confused from the above, but it seems Jeremy Murray-Wakefield's answer works but only if you have version 24.3 of Adobe illustrator (which came out sometime in late August of 2020). The new feature is the "Vertical text alignment" ability, described here https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/whats-new/2020-3.html#vertical-align and also https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/align-text.html#vertical-align

(this would have been appropriate as a response to Jeremy Murray-Wakefield's post but I don't have high enough reputation to post comments, sorry).

Comment: Thank you. I've added this information to Jeremy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for some instances.

1) Make sure your type is Area type (Type > Convert To Area Type)

2) Type > Area Type Options, select the Auto Size checkbox

3) Open the Appearance panel (Window > Appearance)

4) Add a stroke (or fill, or both). With your stroke selected, click the *fx* button and choose: Convert to Shape; select the shape of your choice (rectangle, rounded rectangle or ellipse).

5) Click the *fx* name and adjust the parameters to suit your requirement (Absolute, Relative, Width/Extra Width, Height/Extra Height, etc.).

6) Once you have one set up right you can alt-drag the settings to other strokes/fills in your appearance stack.

7) Once you are happy your shape fits your project, save it as a graphic style so you can apply it with just one click.

8) Raise your hands skywards and proclaim "Halleluja" (or other suitable exclamation of joy).

Answer (score -3):

When you type a text. There should be a saying "Paragraph like this"
[http://imgur.com/90lL0cl](https://imgur.com/90lL0cl)

Then you align it to the right or left or in the center.
I hope this has have helped!

Comment: They are asking about aligning the text vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score -3):

Paragraph Align

1) Select the "Type," "Area Type" or "Vertical Area Type" tool.

2) Click in the text frame that contains vertical text.

3) Click on the "Window" menu and hover over "Type." Select "Paragraph" to activate the paragraph panel.

4) Select the "Align Top," "Align Center" or "Align Bottom" icons in the paragraph panel or on the control panel. The paragraph of text will adjust to the top, center or bottom of the text frame.

Align to Object

5) Hold down the "Shift" key, and select the area type and the object that you want to align the type with.

6) Click on the "Window" menu, and select "Align" to activate the "Align" Panel.

7) Select the desired alignment icon from the align panel. Illustrator automatically moves the text frame and the object to align the text frame with the selected object.

Comment: there is no "align bottom", "align top" in illustrator. you are talking about another software.

Comment: bro i work in that only for logo designing.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6qKgnLq.jpg

Comment: no doubt but I am talking about "Paragraphs" and text area where there is no such option. maybe a screenshot will explain more your point. please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot but this is not what I am talking about it is something like that [example](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flash/articles/page_layouts_tlf/fig10.jpg) how to do it using illustrator?

Answer (score -3):

After almost half an hour going through so many answers and not able to understand. I did some hit and try and found a very very simple solution.

Just select the text in the text box
right click
select "object Properties"
a toolbar shall open in the right hand side
got to option "Frame"
just move your cursor on the available options and it shall show you the vertical alignment possibilities.

Comment: there's no such option in Illustrator