# Center text vertically in a text box Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know it's not possible in CS5, now we have CC with more functions so does anyone know if there is a button to centre type vertically in a text box in Illustrator CC?

I am creating lots of templates with text boxes that have many different numbers of lines and are being edited frequently so type needs to sit in center of box vertically automatically. The workarounds in other threads do not help me, for example selecting the boxes elements above and below them to centre each time content is updated is not an efficient method as there are over 30 text boxes multiplied by 25+ templates.

QUESTION ANSWERED:
This functionality is not supported in Illustrator CC.

Many thanks.

Comment: It is possible to do with scripting, but it is far from ideal. I am also in search of a method for doing this in a more native way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center text in a box in Illustrator CS5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10700/how-to-vertically-center-text-in-a-box-in-illustrator-cs5) & [How can I align text in a text area vertically, in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42030/how-can-i-align-text-in-a-text-area-vertically-in-illustrator)

Comment: It's different, we are now asking if functionality exists in CC.

Comment: The question is not _that_ different... and no, it doesn't unfortunately. However, as some people mention every time this question resurfaces, this feature exists in Indesign. — In your specific situation, I don't think there's anything you can do Illustrator to get past this issue. — I don't know how people typically handle this or if they just ignore the issue and leave recentering to the end-user.

Comment: Not that different, but different none-the-less. If i'm searching for info, I want to know the functionality of the LATEST software, not a program that was released 10 years ago. That the functionality still does not exist in CC is the answer to my question, thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of those questions I linked made no mention of the version number, which would mean it's not limited to answers about cs5.

Comment: That link was to a discussion taking place in 2014. Not unreasonable to see if the community had any more recent information.

Comment: @BrianBrenda: This site does not operate like this. Old questions can receive updated answers if the facts change. In fact, the proposed duplicate received an answer a month ago. If you want to solicit new answer to an old question, you can place a [bounty](/help/bounty) on it, once you have sufficient reputation. If your situation differs from the one in the existing questions other than by being more recent, please [edit] it to be more specific than “The workarounds in other threads do not help me”.

Comment: Also, I deleted completely unnecessary [non-niceness](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) from some comments.

Comment: Thank you Wrzlprmft, I received the answer that I was looking for from Joonas, i.e. it's not possible in CC. I couldn't find that answer in the other threads. Anyone else searching for this answer will hopefully find it more quickly now and save the time of trying various work-arounds listed in the duplicate threads that don't work.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If you mean like this use Type on vertical path

If you mean how to get it to follow a specific vertical path use type on path after drawing the path w/ the pen tool

If you're looking for something else I'd need a better explanation

Comment: I think [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0a2H.jpg) from one of the duplicate links I posted below the question describes the need pretty well. What he wants is to center the text just like in the second text frame.