# How to anchor text to bottom-right of container?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment

When I use the Type tool in Illustrator, text automatically flows from the top-left:

[image]

Is it possible to have the text flow from the bottom-right instead, like this (Illustrator CC 2014)?

[image]

The Paragraph toolbox doesn't have any setting to do this, and the Type tool doesn't present anything that intuitively does this.  Google turns up very little apart from anchoring the whole shape to another.

Comment: This is not exactly duplicate, but it discusses the issue of vertically aligning in Illustrator and the selected answer gives an answer to this question as well: [How to vertically center text in a box in Illustrator CS5](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10700/how-to-vertically-center-text-in-a-box-in-illustrator-cs5)

Comment: The tutorial simply aligns objects, and not text, in an extremely crude fashion that means the text objects needs to be resized to push the text downward before alignment can occur!  The best comment on that page is, *"Adobe is so very broken in so very many ways"* as it appears it cannot natively be done without downloading scripts.  Very surprising and very disappointing!

Comment: This is very easy to do in InDesign which is the better tool for typography. Did you only do a 1-app license or do you have the entire CC suite?

Comment: Yes I've got the whole suite but have never installed InDesign

Answer (score 1):

[image: Align bottom right]

As of the latest Illustrator Update, this functionality is available in the top toolbar (oddly enough it seems to be missing from the paragraph pane) – *now making Illustrators text-justification tools equally powerful as other professional-level layout programs like...powerpoint!*

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Using point text instead of area text allows for text to be precisely positioned at a set distance to the bottom right corner. When the text is changed/edited the position relative to the corner will stay the same. Obviously this does not offer a perfect solution, but it might be a step in the right direction?

Comment: Well that is was not what the aster asked. They asked is it possible for text to flow into right bottom corner of a area text. I mean presumably they know how to position text but since its a placeholder they need it to flow to right place. If this is your take then you need to explain that ist not possible and describe this as a workaround.

Comment: As I started my answer with stating that "it was not a complete solution but it might help in specific cases" I hoped to have been clear enough. As I am a new member of stack Exchange I would like to apologise for any wrongdoing.

Comment: you might have noitoced that your answer is on -1. That wasn't me. So clearly others think this too. This is not a forum, this is a Q/A site so you should strive to have an answer. Answering can not be done is valid though people do not like giving that answer.  But this is not really a good answer the way its written. Change that line into an not be done and eliminate 50% of what you wrote and its fine.

Comment: thank you joojaa for your guidance. sorry I could not help to find an answer to this.