# How to apply Graphic Style correctly in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, highlights, graphic-styles

This is my first time to post a question. My question should be a best following to the answer below, but I cannot comment it because it requires 50 reputations (which I have only 1 as a newbie).
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19828/58120

This regards to how to highlight text with background color in Illustrator.
My question is exactly as what @MartinBlick asked. By following @SOIA's instruction, I can successfully make the appearance e.g. black text in yellow background. But when apply the Graphic Style to a new text object, it becomes a yellow block (without showing the text). I think the trick is the "Move new fill below characters" in @SOIA's instruction, because when I clicked back the style of my first successful stance, the new fill becomes above characters again. It seems that the relative position of Fill and Character is not properly saved. Please correct me if I understand this wrongly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). You don't need reputation to answer a question, if this is what you wanted. You can always talk on the http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests to see if I could find out what you were talking about...

I figured it out. What you need to do is this...

- Go into the flyout menu of the Graphic Styles Panel
- Make sure that 'Override Character Color' is unchecked:

[image: Graphic Styles flyout menu]

Then apply your style...

Hope this helps.

Comment: LOL I really need to start paying attention to how old the questions are...