# Illustrator: Auto-sized Text box with a rectangle border (no fill)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, borders, bounding-box

My question is related to this one [Illustrator: Auto-sized Text box with shaded background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19824/illustrator-auto-sized-text-box-with-shaded-background)

What I want is an auto-sized Text box with a black rectangle border. It should look like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in Illustrator?

Comment: Yes . You can after creation select the texbox and give it a stroke. And you can use textbox objects a inset. OR you can use the make square effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the *exact same method* in the [question you linked to](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19828/3270). 
Merely apply a stroke rather than a fill.

- Select the type object
- Add a *new* stroke to it via the **Appearance Panel**. You **must** add a new stroke. This will *not work* on the default stroke for type characters.
- With the stroke highlighted in the **Appearance Panel**, choose `Effect > Convert to Shape > Rectangle` and adjust the settings

[image]

The "box" will then auto-size to match the text.

[image]

---

If you want a **filled rectangle** rather than a stroke, it's the same basic steps. See here: [Illustrator: Auto-sized Text box with shaded background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19824/illustrator-auto-sized-text-box-with-shaded-background)