# Adding a Fill to a Diagonal Text Box in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, fill

The standard answer to the question of how to add a fill to a text box in Illustrator isn't working for me because it assumes that the text is horizontal. I'm creating a map in which virtually all the text is either on a path or at an angle, and the geniuses at Adobe decided that the text box fill should cover the x/y coordinates of the text box rather than the text box itself.

Are there any workarounds other than painstakingly placing a rectangle or stroke object behind every label? (It's a large map with about 500 labels, so the manual approach doesn't have much appeal.) A script or a plug-in perhaps?

[image: diagonal map label]

Comment: Its not assuming text is horisontal it just makes a world aligned box around anything you wish. That is useful for a lot of things that are rotated. But obviously its not the tool for this job. You can script this no problem. Is it a point text or a text in a frame?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: The background fill is created via the Appearance panel and the `Convert to Rectangle` effect. [As described here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19824/illustrator-auto-sized-text-box-with-shaded-background) Note that for this effect to work well, you should *start* with straight horizontal, unrotated, text. Rotate it *after* it has been created using the effect described below.

---

`Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...` Will rotate the text *and* the extra fill. With the added addition of easily editing the rotation again if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fully automated approach, but it may help you. Anything more automated would likely require scripting.

1. Draw a rectangle, and click on the outline with the Area Type tool to add some text to the shape.
2. Use the Direct Selection tool (A), to select the box, open the Appearance Panel and change the fill.
3. Select the text with the Text Tool, and in the Paragraph settings set the text to centred, and in the Character settings adjust the baseline so the text is centred vertically inside the box.

You should end up with something like this

[image]

4. To rotate, use the Rotate Tool (R)
5. Once you have one text box made, you can just copy and paste it for additional labels and edit the the text with the Text Tool.
6. You use the Selection tool (V) to click and drag the edge handle of the box to resize it for longer/shorter text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Billy. That would be the most efficient way to manually add the backgrounds when starting from scratch, but unfortunately I'm having to enlarge ~500 existing labels and retrofit the background fills. Also, ~200 of them are text on paths (curvy country roads), which will require open-path backgrounds rather than rectangles. A clusterf**k.

Realistically this will probably require a scripted solution. :-(

Comment: @Billy Kerr,  Instead of adjusting the baseline you can now center text within a text-box in Illustrator. They added this functionality with the latest release.

Comment: @dom yes absolutely, but not everyone is using the latest version yet (including me).

Comment: @BillGregg - yeah, I feel your pain.

Comment: @BillGregg ahaa the text on path ones should be easy to handle. Just assign a fill to the path (not text) and offset it

Comment: @joojaa Yep, apart from having to trim the ends of the text paths, that solution is pretty painless. Thanks.

Comment: @BillGreg just goes to show that describing what you have is more important than describing  what you dont have ;) if you can edit that info in i can edit this into an answer.

Comment: @Scott Thanks! I wasn't aware of the Transform Effect functionality. That works, though it's probably a toss-up whether it's more efficient to straighten the existing labels and then apply the effect, or just create new labels. 

If I can grouse a little, all this seems excessively complex. Not great software design. Some software package I used to use (Macromedia FreeHand? Indesign?) allowed you to assign a fill to a text box in a simple, straightforward fashion and the fill stayed confined to the text box no matter how you transformed it.