# Remove extra space in front of the text without outlining it? [Illustrator]

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typesetting, white-space

Did anyone figure it out on how to remove that little extra space in front of the text?

[image]

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate question, but the solution works for this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51774/align-text-in-exact-center-vertically-and-horizontally-without-creating-outlin/51780#51780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **[kern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)** your text, not track it (tracking is for adjusting uniform spacing in spans or blocks of text, kerning is for adjusting individual letter spacing).

Kerning is located in the character palette, below font size and left of tracking (CS6). To use it, select the type tool and place the text cursor on the left side of the letter you want to adjust (the "E" here). Keep in mind:

- Negative numbers will shift your text left.
- The units are 1/1000 [em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)),
  so you may need to enter a large number like -100.
- You need to be using [area type](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-text.html) (which is where your type is
  contained in a closed shape, such as when you click and drag with the
  type tool to make a box, or click a closed shape with the type tool
  and enter some text), because you won't get the desired result using
  [point type](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-text.html) (when you single click and enter text with the
  type tool) or [type on a path](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-text.html).

See also: 
[Kerning on the Illustrator docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/line-character-spacing.html)

Comment: As far as I know, Kerning doesn't affect the first letter, only the ones after it in relation to the first letter...

Comment: It does (works/tested).

Comment: I've also tried it and it doesn't move the first letter...also, the Adobe Docs example back me up and also say "Kerning is the process of adding or subtracting space **between** specific pairs of characters. "...Something's off here, I'll try with another font.

Comment: I am back and it **kinda** works, the thing that you forgot to mention is that you need to put a space before the first character for this to work. This may very well be a workaround but it kinda kills the editable quality of the text by no shifting the editable area itself too...and it can drive you crazy when using this in large documents and trying to edit later.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but it definitely works on the first character in any piece of text, no space needed before. What was happening before when you entered your number? Your cursor should be placed to the left of the first character (the "E").

Comment: For me, at first, it didn't wanna let me set a negative value before the first letter if I didn't place a space before it and it didn't allow the text to be edited properly. Now, everything is working fine. I guess AI was playing some tricks on me due to the fact I am working in it now and it's a large document :)) +1 My friend.

Comment: Edited my answer to point at yours as the correct one ;)

Comment: @alin, this doesn't solve the problem though...It's not actually closing the space between the first character and the edge of the text box, it's just shifting the entire box to the left.

Comment: This does not move the box, John. It moves the type inside of the box to the left. (Edited to correct typos)

Comment: I'm trying it right now in AI CC 2015 and my entire box is getting shifted left.  The space doesn't change.

Comment: @JohnManly It will move the box only if the negative value is higher than needed, I had the same reaction at first until I started playing with the values and with the right one it will only move the first letter at the beginning of the box. ;)

Comment: But still, the space between the character and the box is not affected.  That was the point of the original question, was it not?  How to close the space?  http://imgur.com/a/9rJAO

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're using type on a path and not a text box here. You need to use a text box.

Comment: Not text on a path, just using the default text tool.  I see that the method _does_ work, if you click + drag to draw out a text box, but that's not what was done in the original post.

Comment: When you single click somewhere with the type tool and start typing, it essentially does the same thing. It's called "point type", see here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-text.html

Comment: And I should add, when you are kerning your point type and see a box around it, that's the transform/bounding box. It doesn't mean you're using area type (also in the link) aka a text box.

Comment: I get the difference between type entry techniques.  What I'm saying, though, is that this question was posted using point type.  This adjustment does not remove the space between the first character and the transform/bounding box in point type mode.  This method shifts the entire box to the left, the space is unchanged.

Comment: I don't think the original question specifies that this is point type. The box you're talking about moving here is the bounding box, not a structural box/real path that has bearing on where your type sits or how it is aligned using other tools (hit shift+ctrl+b to see what's really there). I'll edit my answer later to add some clarity.

Comment: Just by looking at the transform/bounding box around the text in the image posted by the asker, you can tell that it's point type.  Area and path type have different looking boxes.

Comment: And the transform/bounding box definitely does affect the alignment.  If I select the text and another object and I horizontally align them left, the text will be aligned according to the edge of the transform/bounding box, therefore having the unwanted space on the left.

Comment: You're right, the image does seem to be missing the in-port for threading text that would appear on an area type object. Still, I think it's clear that this question is not specifically making a point of asking for a solution for point type in particular. I don't know of any way to change this for point type since it's baked in letter spacing in the font and there's no real/explicit path which denotes an actual box. As I said though, I'll update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT:

> While everything I said in my answer is true, the answer that you are looking for is **Qutorial's answer** below. It's tested and it works nicely. Keep in mind that while using his method you need to be in text-editing mode with the focus in front of the first letter, only then you can change the value from auto (or 0) to a negative one!

---

I'm sorry to say but as far as I know you can't get rid of that space without outlining the font.

That space is due to the font's creation, not something illustrator puts there.
Like shown below, different fonts have different spaces. (You may find some that have almost no space.)

[image]

Comment: I think you are right, but I'm going to wait a bit more maybe someone has figured it out, if not I will select your answer

Comment: @Eli Best of luck my friend, hope you find your best answer. PS: Setting a negative value to font indent won't help either...I checked before posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, this is a font issue, not an Illustrator one.  I've noticed this happening in other Adobe programs as well, not only AI.

My workaround for this is a simple one and involves placing a space in front of your first character, then you adjust the tracking of the space to a negative value, until it lines up where you'd like it.

In the following example, the top is my regular point text - no adjustments.  The bottom is the same exact text, but with a space and negative tracking.

**I should add, since it was apparently not easy to understand, that you only adjust the tracking of the space, not the other characters.**

[image: example]

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this a workaround? What this does is complicate the situation. The OP obviously didn't want to outline the text to keep it editable, since he wants it editable, he will not have only one letter in there. With a negative tracking , all the other letters will overlap the E...even in his example, he still has an L after the E.

Comment: @Alin You only apply the negative tracking to the space...NOT the rest of the letters.  I said tracking, but I guess I meant kerning?  They are essentially the same thing, only one applies to one letter and the other to the entire block of text...semantics, I suupose

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to be able to align the text with other objects, a simple option is to turn on **Optical Margin Alignment**: Type > Optical Margin Alignment. Some portions of characters, such as serifs, may extend slightly beyond the text area as Illustrator attempts a more pleasing character alignment, but this will probably be acceptable and the space before the first character will certainly be gone.

Answer (score -4):

Can't be done. It's there for some reason.