# Precisely resize editable text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, resize, bounding-box

I want to be able to resize editable text (to a precise numerical value) but it goes by the bounding box, which is slightly larger than the text is. The only way to reduce the bounding box on editable text is to convert it to outlines which makes it non editable.

Is there any way I can precisely resize (editable) text in Adobe Illustrator?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

---

See, also, [this YouTube video where I explain the problem more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp2fLkfImq8).

Comment: That link shows video unavailable. Mind uploading a GIF?

Comment: So sorry it should work now, ( it was set to private)

Comment: I don't think it is possible... aside from expanding the text or just scaling it close enough by eyeing it.

Comment: Convert to outlines. Calculate exact change percentage. Undo the outlines, and apply the scale percentage.

Comment: Same method here will work, **without** creating outlines -- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51774/align-text-in-exact-center-vertically-and-horizontally-without-creating-outlin  --- The effect, combined with preference settings, will see the edge of glyphs as the bounding area, same as outlined type, but without outlining.

Answer (score 1):

- Make a rectangle the same height as the letter
- Select the rectangle and the letter
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Win to create a **Clipping Mask**
- Change the height value, make sure the **Lock proportions** icon is checked
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>7</kbd> Win to release the **Clipping Mask**
- Delete the rectangle

[image: mask]