# Extra space beneath font

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]I am facing a problem. I want to apply 'vertical-align bottom' between the word 'voice and the circle. The extra space beneath the word 'voice' dsnt let that happen. I want to get rid of the extra space (red marked) from this word. How can I do that?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51774/align-text-in-exact-center-vertically-and-horizontally-without-creating-outlin

Comment: Thank you, Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create outlines (select the text and then go to *Type > Create Outlines*) from the text. Once you create outlines, it becomes like *normal* vectors, just like your circle, then you can align it properly with circle.

As you can see, after creating outlines, that white space disappeared.

[image]

If you don't want to expand, you can manually drag it down if you aren't worried about *perfection*.

Comment: Thank you, Tried both. I actually was thinking if there is any other way in the character panel setting.

Comment: I wanna know why the font has this extra space beneath them. what is the purpose. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin I don't know any other option. This is what I do most of the time.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin I think it has something to do with character/line spacing. Not very sure. Will update if I find it out.

Comment: Gotcha :D    :D    :D    :D    :D    :D

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin you can read Scott's answer here for the same: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51774/align-text-in-exact-center-vertically-and-horizontally-without-creating-outlin

Comment: yeah...   am reading that right now.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin the extra space is there because that's how the author created it. It's often to compensate for descenders or accents within the range of glyphs.

Comment: Wow....  it was killing me... I really wanna know why they put it there in the first place. Thank you, Scott. <3

Comment: The issue is generally less common with higher quality fonts.

Comment: In recent versions of Illustrator, there’s a setting to choose the alignment basis for text – you can choose baseline, x-height, etc. You should just be able to choose the baseline there, and that should do it. (I don’t use Illustrator that much, so I don’t remember off-head where this setting is or exactly how it works, but it’s there somewhere.)